# Shapes don't respect map's 'draggable' property

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Edge scrolling**

Let's say I've created a simple map with default options, a draggable marker and a draggable shape (I've tested it with circle, rectangle, polygon and polyline). When I drag the marker or shape to the edge of map canvas, the map starts scrolling and that's fine.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k9Gbh/)</kbd>

**The problem**

When I set map's draggable property to false, the edge scrolling doesn't work anymore with the marker, but all the shapes ignore it and the map is still scrolled - and that's unexpected behaviour.

```
var mapOptions = {
    ...
    draggable: false
};
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fJyJ9/)</kbd>

The problem exists in both release (3.16) and experimental (3.17) versions. I've reported it on [google's bugtracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6917), but it will probably take years before they fix it. So, does anyone know a workaround?

Edit: for the sake of simplicity, let's assume that zooming the map is also disabled

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a bug, the map scolls(pans), but IMO this is no dragging-operation on the map(it's more panning executed by the API). Setting the draggable-option to false will not prevent the map from viewport-changes.

Comment: You are a bug finder!

Comment: @Dr.Molle, the behaviour is inconsistent. Either both of them should scroll or not.

Comment: The behaviour is inconsistent, but it's not specified, so you can't expect a specific behaviour.

Comment: Agreed with above comment. Do you need a solution to fix the behavior to your needs?

Comment: Yes, that's why I've asked this question.

Comment: When I say *solution*, that's going to be a fix to allow you to constrain a shape within the map bounds.

Comment: It's not that simple, adding constraints to shape will still trigger map panning. It's possible to lock map center, but it causes the shape to 'run away'. Take a look at the demo here, try dragging the circle slowly: http://jsfiddle.net/JhC4e/

Comment: Yes I know and that's not the way I'd do it.

Comment: I need a way to prevent auto panning for shapes that also works with complex shapes like polygons and takes the relative position of mouse into the account, so you can actually move your mouse to the edge and shape will partially go outside the map bounds. Do you have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google [fixed it](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6917) in version 3.19, it now works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to listen to the map `zoom_changed`, `bounds_changed` and the circle `dragend` events.

If the shape is dragged outside of the defined bounds, set it back to its last position and set the map center to the original value.

```
function initialize() {

    var bounds = null;
    var zoomLevel = 15;
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(20.291, 153.027);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: zoomLevel,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        draggable: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: center,
        draggable: true
    });

    var circlePos = new google.maps.LatLng(20.281, 153.037);

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        center: circlePos,
        radius: 100,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#000000',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        draggable: true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {

        // If user changes zoome level, get the new level and the new map bounds
        zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
        bounds = map.getBounds();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {

        // Get the initial map bounds if not set yet
        if (!bounds) {

            bounds = map.getBounds();
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'dragend', function () {

        var position = circle.getCenter();

        if (bounds.contains(position)) {

            // Update the circle position
            circlePos = position;

        } else {

            // Set the circle back to its last position
            // Reset the map center as it might have changed
            circle.setCenter(circlePos);
            map.setCenter(center);
        }
    });
};
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/7yH5X/)</kbd>

Kindly note that you can eliminate the `zoom_changed` event listener if you disable the zooming options on your map. Problem if a user can use the zoom is that your shape can still disappear from the map bounds if the user zooms in, which can be confusing.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't disable auto panning, it just moves back the shape to it's previous position. And it also doesn't allow moving a shape to an edge of the map.

Comment: Well then what about turning your circle into a marker icon?

Comment: Good luck with turning editable polygons into marker icons ;)

Comment: Do you have a specific use case? Or are you just looking for bugs?

Comment: Well unless someone has an idea how to modify this behavior, I think you'll have to rely on your bug reports / feature requests.